# Where do Jersey json serialization errors get logged?

Tags: java, json, jersey

This dead simple jersey request fails with server error 500.  I'm pretty sure it is on serialization.  I had another object that was doing the same thing and I stepped through in the debugger and discovered some member wasn't serializable.

Anyway, my question - where does jersey logs the root cause of these problems?   They're not going into the tomcat logs.  When I was in the debugger, it was getting logged to something, but I could quite figure out where it was going.

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, String> getProps() {
        Properties props =   System.getProperties();
        Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();

        for (Object o : props.keySet()) {
            String key = (String) o;
            results.put(key, props.getProperty(key));
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey uses the JDK logging API. Here is a tutorial for setting it up: http://yatel.kramolis.cz/2013/11/how-to-configure-jdk-logging-for-jersey.html